# Rails, Devise, and Facebook Oauth: request.env["omniauth.auth"] is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, oauth-2.0

I'm using Facebook Oauth and Devise in my rails app. I successfully get taken to the facebook login page, but then get an error on the callback action. Tracked it down to `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` returning `nil` in my callback action.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

Routes:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/users/auth/facebook/callback', to: 'users/omniauth_callbacks#facebook'
  end

  resources :users
  devise_for :users, path: '', path_names: { sign_up: 'register', sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout'}, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }
```

initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Figaro.env.facebook_key, Figaro.env.facebook_secret,
                scope: 'email,public_profile',
                callback_url: Figaro.env.facebook_callback_url
```

User.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, 
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :confirmable, :validatable,
          :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]
```

omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb:

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

 def facebook

    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
     request.env["omniauth.auth"]   ## <<=== this is nil
```

Any idea why my `request.env["omniauth.auth"]` is returning `nil`?

Comment: Did you find solution so far?

Answer (score 3):

So finally i am able to find the issue, i was also struggling with the same issue for a long time, but now we have the solution, ok here we go:

The problem is with the devise.rb, just remove this from the file:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, Figaro.env.facebook_key, Figaro.env.facebook_secret,
                scope: 'email,public_profile',
                callback_url: Figaro.env.facebook_callback_url
```

and then restart your server and then try to get login through facebook.

You will get what you want :)

Thanks, Enjoy Coding :)